# inserting date field into sqlite database with javascript failed

Tags: javascript, sqlite, jquery-mobile, datepicker

no value inserted in the date field of sqlite database

```html
<label for="DateDebut">Date Debut</label>
<input name="DateDebut" id="DateDebut" type="date" data-role="datebox"   data-  
options='{"mode": "calbox"}' />
```

and the insert code

```js
var DateDebut = document.getElementById('DateDebut'); 
function insertRecord() {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql(insertStatement, [nom.value, DateDebut.value, DateFin.value, 
      Message.value], loadAndReset, onError);
    });
  }
```

When inserting the record in the database the date value remains empty as no date was entered.

Comment: Check that whatever date string is coming out of the `.value` is something that SQLlite can handle directly - you may have to massage it into an acceptable format, e.g.`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` before you can simply insert it.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: the '.value' is well shown in the alert box , and its type is string and the date field in the DB is with the type TEXT so the 2 types are normally compatibles and i still wonder why it is not inserted in the DB

Comment: The SQLite record structure would help find the answer.